# Disabling mtu_bypass on AIX in file

Tags: aix, puppet

I would like to disable mtu_bypass from within a file. I saw that you can use chdev to do it with a command, but I would rather specify the setting within a file using puppet.

Does anyone know which file / syntax is used to disable mtu instead of doing it with a command?

thanks,

Comment: It *is* a device setting; you could, in theory, put a chdev command in a startup script.

Comment: @JeffSchaller what I don't understand is if it is a device setting, how it is not stored anywhere? It must be otherwise when I reboot it will be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

AIX stores device configuration in ODM (files), which you manipulate via commands (e.g. `chdev`).

For mtu_bypass in particular, see this Developerworks article by Chris Gibson: [New virtual Ethernet adapter attribute for largesend on AIX](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/cgaix/entry/virtual_ethernet_adapters_largesend_on_aix1?lang=en) where it says:

> The new attrribute is called mtu_bypass and can be changed with the chdev command ...
>
> `chdev -l en1 -a mtu_bypass=on`

and queried with the command:

`lsattr -El en1 -a mtu_bypass`